# How to make an Excel data connection without a DSN?

Tags: excel, connection-string, dsn

We have a tool from a vendor that comes with instructions for us geeks to build a DSN for it to work.

Unfortunately (1) it isn't a geek that would use it; (2) we don't want to keep having to "fix it" every time they get on a different computer; and (3) we don't want all the DSNs left on the previous computers, since they contain DB passwords in plain text.

I have often in the past used a connection string without a DSN to do this sort of thing.  But THIS time, Excel complains that it can't find a DSN in the connection string.

Comment: [ConnectionStrings](http://connectionstrings.com) might help. It's difficult to say why your current effort isn't working when you don't show us your current effort at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest difference between all the conection strings that didn't work is that they tried to use OLE.  ODBC worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an OleDB connection with either the Jet or Ace provider?  See here:

[Excel Connection Strings (OleDb)](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

Comment: Turns out that OLE *was* the problem.  It worked when I changed to ODBC.